# Meta-analysing impact of Covid pandemic on risk for perforated appendicitis

Tags: meta-analysis, count-data, paired-data, covid-19

I am analyzing the impact of the change in the management of appendicitis during the covid pandemic. I have paired data from 31 reports comparing the number of operations for perforated and nonperforated appendicitis during the lockdown period compared with that during the same time period in 2019. So essentially I have data with 5 columns - author, number of perforated and nonperforated patients during the pre-covid and during lockdown periods. The reports are from small and large hospitals so the numbers of patients vary considerably in size from 13 to 1000

A common conclusion in these reports is that the proportion of perforations increased during the lockdown, suggesting that the delay has caused more appendices to perforate.

However, in many cases, the number of perforations is very similar in both periods or even lower during the lockdown, but the number of non-perforated appendices are often much reduced. The increased proportion of perforations is thus explained by the reduced denominator and not an increased numerator. An explanation could be that more cases of non-complicated appendicitis were allowed to heal spontaneously.

How can I show that the increased proportion of perforations is explained by the decrease of nonperforated cases? And can I estimate the effect of the lockdown on the two types of appendicitis in some way? Unfortunately, I have no data on the catchment population otherwise I could refer to that as the denominator.

In the graph the x-axis is the difference in the proportions (% proportion during the covidperiod)-(% proportion the same period 2019). The Y-axis is the ratio of numer of cases (perforated and non-perforated) during covidperiod/number in 2019. I have added arrows for reports with an increase in proportion of perforations but this is due to a decrease in the non-perforated and not an increase in number of perforated cases.

How can I analyse the impact of the numerator and the denominator on the proportion of perforations statistically?

I use Stata. [image: Association of proportion of perforated appendicitis during Covid period compared with 2019]

Comment: I think you're using a hypothesis to frame the data, rather than the other way around, and no analysis can successfully convince others without reading from a completely biased perspective. I think if admissions for appendicitis are actually *down* in the era of COVID you can show that with an interrupted time series. Similarly you can show incidence of perfs are up. Always focus on simple, uncomplicated analyses first: time series plots, means, and SE bars over time. If these are data from Sweden I have no idea how to measure catchment. In the US, we have GPRA as an imperfect standard.

Comment: That said, my son contracted COVID recovered and was shortly admitted for a perforation in bowel and appendix. The surgeon remarked that, anecdotally, there seems to be a link between infection and perforation. So very interested to see the result of the analysis.

Comment: Not at all. I use already published data but want to take the analysis one step further and analyse which factor is most important for variations in the proportion of perforations - the numerator (number of perforations) or the denominator (total number of appendicitis or non-perforated appendicitis). This is a complementary perspective which few others have looked upon, but is in fact in accordance with epidemiological studies which have shown a decrease in non-perforated appendicitis but stable incidence rate of perforated.